# bash: elementary if-conditions not working? (string comparison)

Tags: bash, if-statement, comparison, string-comparison, boolean-expression

When I run this script in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

str="no"

if [ "$str"="yes" ]; then
    echo "condition 1 is true"
fi

if [ "$str"=="yes" ]; then
    echo "condition 2 is true"
fi

if [[ "$str"="yes" ]]; then
    echo "condition 3 is true"
fi

if [[ "$str"=="yes" ]]; then
    echo "condition 4 is true"
fi

if (( "$str"="yes" )); then
    echo "condition 5 is true"
fi

if (( "$str"=="yes" )); then
    echo "condition 6 is true"
fi
```

To my surprise, I get:

> condition 1 is true
>   condition 2 is true
>   condition 3 is true
>   condition 4 is true
>   condition 5 is true
>   condition 6 is true

Note that `$str` is set to `no`, not `yes`.

I don't fully understand the difference between `=` and `==` (at least, not in this bash context, I do in other languages) or between putting the if condition single `[ ... ]` or double `[[ ... ]]` or double `(( ... ))` brackets.

However I'm obviously something very wrong here, but I can't see it?

Comment: Try entering your code at shellcheck.net.

Comment: You need spaces around the `=` inside `[ ]` and `[[ ]]`. `(( ))` is only for arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, not having a spaces around the operators, you're actually testing (for instance)

```
[ "no=yes" ]
```

which will evaluate as true (non-empty string).

`[...]` is testing using `[` external test command (presumably `/bin/[`) and `[[...]]` is shell (bash or ksh for instance) built-in test. For test `=` and `==` have the same meaning. Which in case of built-in test (`[[...]]`) is actually evaluated for a pattern match: i.e. `[[ yeees == y*s ]]` is also true.

`((...))` is arithmetic evaluation. `=` is an assignment, and `==` tests equality. In my case (could come down to bash version) #5 actually yields false unless I've set `yes=1` beforehand as the evaluation return value assigned... in this case new variable named `no` since that is what `str` pointed (resolved) to. For the comparison, this arithmetic comparison will return true, if values of both variables are equal... which literally means `(( no == yes ))` or in test syntax `[[ "$no" -eq "$yes" ]]`. If neither `no` nor `yes` are set, two 0s are compared.

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the equal signs with spaces. For instance:

```
#!/bin/bash

str="no"

if [ "$str" = "yes" ]; then
    echo "condition 1 is true"
fi
```

...